# Check that smaller cubes fill bigger cube

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry

Given one large cube (axis aligned and on integer coordinates), and many smaller cubes (also axis aligned and on integer coordinates). How can we check that the large cube is perfectly filled by the smaller cubes.

Currently we check that:

1. For each small cube it is fully contained by the large cube.
2. That it doesn't intersect any other small cube.
3. The sum of the volumes of the small cubes equals the volume of the large cube.

This is ok for small numbers of cubes but we need to support this test of cubes with dimensions greater than 2^32. Even at 2^16 the number of small cubes required to fill the large cube is large enough that step 2 takes a while (O(n^2) checking each cube intersects no other).

Is there a better algorithm?

**EDIT:**

There seems to be some confusion over this. I am not trying to split a cube into smaller cubes. That's already done. Part of our program splits large OpenCL ranges (axis aligned cubes on integer coordinates) into lots of smaller ranges that fit into a hardware job.

What I'm doing is hooking into this system and checking that the jobs it produces correctly cover the large initial range. My algorithm above works, but it's slow and given the amount of tests we have to run I'd like to keep these tests as fast as possible.

Comment: Early Fail Test: if you add up the volume of all smaller cubes and it is not equal to the volume of the container, you are done.

Comment: If you overlap all the small cubes in one of the corners of the large cube, you will fail step 2 in his validation, no intersection between smaller cubes.

Comment: Are the cube axis accuracy floating point values, or integer values? Meaning, can you have a cube that is 0.5 wide? Or are all cubes integer-sized?

Comment: They are all integers. "(axis aligned and on integer coordinates)"

Comment: [R-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) might be worth looking into (I haven't worked with them before). It also looks like O(n^2) though, at least in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

We are talking about 3D right?
For 2D one can do a similar (but simpler) process (with, I believe, an O(n log n) running time algorithm).

The basic idea of the below is [the sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).

Note that rectangle intersection can done by checking whether any corner of any cube is contained in any other cube.

**You can improve on (2) as follows:**

- Split each cube into 2 rectangles on the y-z plane (so you'd have 2 rectangles defined by the same set of 4 (y,z) coordinates, but the x coordinates will be different between the rectangles).

  Define the rectangle with the smaller x-coordinate as the start of a cube and the other rectangle as the end of a cube.

  [image]
- Sort the rectangles by x-coordinate
- Have an initially empty [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)
  (each interval should also store a reference to the rectangle to which it belongs)
- For each rectangle:

  - Look up the y-coordinate of each point of the rectangle in the interval tree.
    For each matching interval, look up its rectangle and check whether the point is also contained within the z-coordinates (this is all that's required because the tree only contains x-coordinates in the correct range and we check the y-coordinates by doing the interval lookup).
    If it is, we have overlap.
  - If the rectangle is the start of a cube, insert the 2 y-coordinates of the rectangle as an interval into the interval tree.
  - Otherwise, remove the interval defined by the 2 y-coordinates from the tree.

The running time is between O(n) (best case) and O(n<sup>2</sup>) (worst case), depending on how much overlap there is in the x- and y-coordinates (more overlap is worse).

Comment: Of the answers so far this looks the most promising. Maybe I misunderstand but would I not have to repeat the Y steps for Z as well?

Comment: No, that's not what I was I thinking. Each interval should have a reference to its rectangle. When you found a point to be inside an interval, you look up the rectangle and check if the point also lies within the Z-coordinates. Yes, this could result in needing to check many rectangles. **~||~** As an alternative, I suppose you could get all the intervals for both Y and Z and check which rectangles are contained in both by intersecting the sets of rectangles, but this should take roughly the same amount of time, possibly slightly worse in the average case.

Answer (score 0):

- order your insert cubes
- insert the biggest insert cube in one of the corners of your cube and split up the remaining cube into subcubes
- insert the second biggest insert cube in the first of the sub cubes that will fit and add the remaining subcubes of this subcube to the set of subcubes
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another go, again only addressing step 2 in the original question:

1. Define a space-filling curve with good spatial locality, such as a [3D Hilbert Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve).
2. For each cube calculate the pair of coordinates on the curve for the points at which the curve both enters and leaves the cube. The space-filling curve will enter and leave some cubes more than once, calculate more than one pair of coordinates for these cases.
3. You've now got I don't know how many pairs of coordinates, but I'd guess no more than `2^18`. These coordinates define intervals along the space-filling curve, so sort them and look for overlaps.

Time complexity is probably dominated by the sort, space complexity is probably quite big.

Comment: Finding the points on the curve for each cube doesn't sound easy (or fast). And I'm going to have as many intervals as I have cubes at least. So while checking 1D intervals for overlap is easier than 3D the setup cost probably outweighs it.